# Unable to Send Commands to Omxplayer from Dired

Tags: dired, inputs, video

When opening a video file with [Omxplayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer) through `dired` using `dired-do-shell-command`, I am unable to send commands to the external program to, for example, pause the video. The file plays fine but all keyboard input gets sent to the buffer from which the file was launched.

This occurs on my **Raspberry Pi** running **Arch Linux ARM** on a *TTY*. Does anyone have an idea of what I can do to curb this behavior and force **Emacs** to allow other programs to accept keyboard input?

**EDIT**: To get to my issue, I've ran `emacs -q` then `C-x d` to open the directory containing a video file. While the file is at point in dired, run `dired-do-shell-command` (with `!` if you'd like) and type `omxplayer RET`. The video plays as normal over **Emacs** and I expect to be able to pause the video with `SPC` or seek with `<right>` and `<left>` but instead of going to **Omxplayer**, those commands runs in `dired`. I'm not sure what else to try. The same process works fine in the **Vim File Manager** (vifm). It seems **Emacs** is running the shell command asyncronously even though I've specified for it not too.

Comment: You do not say what you've already tried. Please provide more info - perhaps a step-by-step recipe of what you do, including what you see and what you expected to see instead. That will help others help you.

Comment: Hi Drew, I've added some more details. I hope it helps with understanding the sitatuation I'm trying to describe. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else.